# Where are the outer limits?

Tags: nuance

When one talks about the "outer limits" of something, what, or where, does it mean exactly? (I mean, where to pinpoint?)

Thinking of a limit as an outermost line, is it the area *closest to* this boundary, or is it anywhere *outside of* it?

I'm inclined to say it's the latter, just because of "outer space", yet I guess no one will talk of an inner, just metaphysically, like, in meditation.

**edit**: It's an expression that I cannot tell whether I came across 'till I've just read "explore the outer limits of boredom". What makes me ask if it's common usage for an emphatic "far away", or carries this humorous feel to it (as in the verse).

Comment: Do you have a particular context? It generally means something quite far away but it's impossible to pinpoint without more information. In some contexts it may have a specific meaning (e.g. a city) but often it will be much vaguer.

Comment: I would guess that most older people in the US associate this with the TV show "The Outer Limits", and don't really have any other context they can relate it to.

Comment: I don't think the collocation ***the outer limits*** would normally be used in contexts where some precise ***boundary*** could be identified, so the question is fairly meaningless.

Comment: Like I said, didn't think about that expression until some lyrics by Pet Shop Boys haha. So the question has to do more with the undertone (humor, irony, hyperbole). A spatial "limit" as an absolute notion makes it weird for comparatives (inner/outer), but there's often the idiomatic/ allusive side of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's somewhat ambiguous and nuanced in the meaning - it's basically describing an intangibly distant notional boundary without placing an exact measurement to the boundary (whether it's physical or hypothetical in nature)

> The outer limits of the solar system
> The outer limits of the known universe
> The outer limits of our knowledge

There's no set point here, but there's the notion of reaching out and extending.

By contrast:

> Reaching the speed limit
> Budgets have been stretched to the absolute limit
> Place numbers to this event are limited

These examples imply a defined stopping point to whatever is "limited".

Answer (score -1):

In this instance "outer" seems to be used somewhat honorifically and doesn't add significant meaning to "limits".